# HTML5; finding what is near me with geolocation

Tags: mysql, sql, html, geolocation, geo

Disclaimer: I am slow learner;  I have a list of 300 businesses with address and grid coordinates.  I know how to request a users location with HTML5 Geolocation.  How do I use that information to determine which businesses are nearest to the user?  I have found allot of tutorials but nothing exact and I'm lost.  I am open to any technology or language to do this yet I would like to keep it simple.  I have an IIS7 server and an OSX server and I could create a My SQL database or use SQL server 2008.

Comment: look up the haversine function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the distance between two points using Haversine or similar, see here - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Then you just need to return all those points that fall within a certain radius of your originating point.